# $event object inside $http.get AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events

I am currently doing a web application with AngularJS and a consumable API using SlimPHP.

When I register a user, I need to perform a check using a GET method. Depending on  this method returns, I should run the `$event.preventDefault()` or not.

The code of AngularJS is the following:

```
$scope.checkEmails = function(e){
  var req = $http.get(url + 'adv/register/check?email=' + $scope.email).then(function(response){
      if(response.data === true) {
        e.preventDefault()
      }
  })
}
```

And the HTML button is this:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-alt-success" ng-click="checkEmails($event)">
```

The problem is that, when i try to execute the `e.preventDefault()`, **inside scope of $http call the object $event is undefined.**

So, **how i can pass this object inside $http call**, or **how i can get the values from $http call outside of their scope** to make the check outside the call.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you modify https://plnkr.co/edit/RHPyWhP2Eql7DopXDCBr?p=preview and update the question with what you are looking for. I am not getting any such error.

Comment: I try this solution too. In my case, the `e.preventDeafult()` don't stop the submit.

Comment: You need to create a plunkr to get your solution. Show me how you have written and what you are expecting. Without a demo code I think I wont be able to much as Nandita has already provided you some approaches. Better to see what you are doing than throwing darts in the dark :)

Comment: Consider using [`$asyncValidators`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$asyncValidators) to asynchronously validate the email. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Custom Validation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation).

Comment: Another approach is to use [`ng-submit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) on the form element. For more information, see [AngularJS `<form>` directive - Submitting a form and preventing the default action](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form#submitting-a-form-and-preventing-the-default-action).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setup will never work because the form is submitted long before the `$http` request is resolved. A button with `type="submit"` will submit its referring form immediately; due to JS asynchronous nature a delayed `preventDefault()` has no effect. So avoid submitting the form through a submit button and do it by code instead. There is multiple ways, in plain JS :

```js
document.getElementById('formId').submit()
```

i.e:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-alt-success" ng-click="checkEmails()">
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

```js
$scope.checkEmails = function(e) {
  $http.get(url + 'adv/register/check?email=' + $scope.email).then(function(response){
    if (response.data !== true) {
      document.getElementById('formId').submit()        
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: With the AngularJS Framework, it is better to use the [ng-submit directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit).

Comment: hey @georgeawg, can you explain why `ng-submit` should be better in this particular case? Considered that, and I agree that if you have some narrow `$scope` two-way binding to elements or similar, then you should use a directive. However, most basic directives are just wrappers for simple code to avoid race conflicts and so on, if that is not the case vanilla JS is the exact same without the digest overhead. But perhaps I am too much "atheist" here :) ?? The code would look more "angularish", I also agree to that, but we are just talking about submitting a form,  `$scope` handlers will work...

Comment: When you go outside the AngularJS framework, it makes unit testing and end-to-end testing more difficult. When you bypass the declarative style of the framework is makes the code more difficult to understand, test, debug, and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$scope.checkEmails = function(e){

  var req = $http.get(url + 'adv/register/check?email=' + $scope.email).then(function(response){
      if(response.data === true) {
        $scope.submitForm =false;
      } else{
         $scope.submitForm = true;
       }
  })
```

Add ng-submit like this

```
<form ng-submit=“submitForm && submit()”>
```

Comment: Thanks, but these solution not work :(. I try u answer but the Form is send because the var `event` is undefined

Comment: Please try my updated answer. You should use ng-submit directive on your form instead of normal submit. It helps you control when the form gets submitted base on conditions inside the directive

Comment: I try the new solution but the form is submitting. I delete the `type="submit"` of `<button>` and the form is sending when i try to get error.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean ! Sorry but this is the best  I could do with this much information

Comment: Finally i am sending form with jQuery inside `if(response.data === true)`. Thank you!

Comment: you are welcome. but dnt know it didnt work for u :(

Comment: Avoid using both the `ngClick` and `ngSubmit` handlers together. For more information, see [AngularJS `<form>` directive - Submitting a form and preventing the default action](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form#submitting-a-form-and-preventing-the-default-action).